# convergent of function series

Tags: calculus

I have a test next week with a question which I do not understand the answer to it.

Let $f_k: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}  \ $ so that $ \ f_k(x) = \frac{1}{k(1+kx)}$

I have to proof that $ \ \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}f_k(x)$ is not uniformly convergent in $ \ (0,\infty)\ $.

So according to [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weierstrass_M-test) I know it was easy to proof that $ \ \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}f_k(x)$ is uniformly convergent in

$ \ \forall a \in \mathbb{R}  \ a>0 \ [a,\infty)\ $.

and according to that I know that I can **not** find a positive series (that convergent) so that foreach

member ($a_n$) in that series we get that $ \forall x \in (0,\infty) \ |f_k(x)| \leq a_k$.

So I saw that proof that this is not uniformly convergent in $(0, \infty)$

we will choose $ \ x_k=\frac{1}{k} \in (0,\infty)$ so we get that

$\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}f_k(x_k) = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{k(1+x_kk)}  = = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{2k} = \frac{1}{2}\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{k} $

which we know that is not convergent.

meaning we found $ \forall \epsilon > 0  \ \ \exists x \in (0,\infty) \  \ \exists N \in \mathbb{N}  \ \ \ $ so that the $N$-tail is not convergent and from

Cauchy criterion we get that the function series is not convergent and therfore

is not uniformly convergent.

I will be happy for some explanation regarding that proof.

By the way, I know that this series is convergent so in order to show that the series does not uniformly

convergent $  \ \exists \epsilon  \ \forall N \in \mathbb{N} \ \exists n > N \ \exists x \in (0, \infty) \ \  |\sum_{k=0}^{n}f_k(x)| \geq \epsilon$

right ?

What most bother me in their proof is that they took not a constant $x$ but $x_n$, why ?

Again I will be happy for a proof

Thanks in advanced !!

Comment: One way to show your series does not converge uniformly is to fix $k$ and let $x=1/k^2$. Then compute $\sum_{n=k}^{k^2} f_n(x)$. You should see this quantity is larger than $\ln k$, which shows the series isn't uniformly Cauchy.

Comment: As for your "By the way", to show the series is not uniformly Cauchy, you need to show there is an $\epsilon>0$ so that for each $N$, there is  $m\ge n\ge N$ and an $x\in(0,\infty)$ with $|\sum_{k=n}^m f_k(x) |\ge\epsilon$.

Comment: Ohhhh.... Thanks. given $\frac{1}{4}$ so for all $ \ N \in \mathbb{N} \ $ we know that $ \ \exists n > N $ and so that for $ \ \frac{1}{n^2} \ $ we get $| \sum_{k=n}^{n^2}f(\frac{1}{n^2})| \ \geq | \sum_{k=n}^{n^2}\frac{1}{2n^2}| = |\frac{n^2 -n}{2n^2}| = |\frac{n-1}{2n}| \geq \frac{1}{4} \ \ $ (the last part is true for all $ \ \mathbb{N}\ $). right ?

Comment: @DavidMitra right ?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're doing. But for $n$ fixed and  $x=1/n$, you have $$\sum_{k=n}^{n^2} f_k(1/n^2)=\sum_{k=n}^{n^2} {1\over k(1+{k\over n^2})}\ge\sum_{k=n}^{n^2} {1\over 2k}.$$ The last sum is, by the integral test, of order $\ln n$.